# RAM needed when using Ubuntu from USB?

Tags: live-usb, ram

Silly question, but do i need RAM, when im planning to use Ubuntu from USB stick?

Comment: Yes, you need RAM just like when using any other hard drive.

Answer (score 4):

Some amount of system memory, aka RAM, is one of the fundamental components of a computer system, along with a processor, power supply, etc.  How much system memory you need is a function of which operating system you choose.  Ubuntu will [need 4 GB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) of RAM.  Other flavors will have different requirements.  Whether the system is booted from a USB or an internal drive does not change the memory requirements.